# Kotlin, smart cast is impossible because of complex expression

Tags: kotlin

I have this code:

```
// allocate one mesh
pScene.mNumMeshes = 1
pScene.mMeshes = mutableListOf(AiMesh())
val pMesh = pScene.mMeshes[0]
```

Where `mMeshes` is a parameter of type

`var mMeshes: MutableList<AiMesh>? = null,`

Compilers complains on the last row, where I try to declare `pMesh`

> Smart cast to `MutableList<AiMesh>` is impossible because `pScene.mMeshes` is a complex expression

What's the problem?

Comment: Does `val pMesh = pScene.mMeshes!![0]` work? If it does, it's because of `mMeshes` being `var` (not guaranteed to be not-null after the assignment).

Comment: Oh god, yes, I didn't think about it.. if you answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since `mMeshes` is a `var` property, it can change between the assignment of `mutableListOf(AiMesh())` and the usage in `pScene.mMeshes[0]`, meaning that it is not guaranteed to be not-null at the use site.

The compiler enforces [null-safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), treating `pScene.mMeshes` as nullable `MutableList<AiMesh>?` and not allowing you to use it as `MutableList<AiMesh>` (i.e. it cannot safely perform a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts)).

To fix that, you can simply make a [non-null assertion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator):

```
val pMesh = pScene.mMeshes!![0]
```

Or just reuse the value you put into the list:

```
val pMesh = AiMesh()
pScene.mMeshes = mutableListOf(mesh)
// use `pMesh` below
```

Comment: Or use something like `val pMesh = AiMesh().apply { pScene.mMeshes = mutableListOf(this) }`