# Why does this Kotlin code still require ?. to access members?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following function in a Kotlin class:

```
private fun raiseResponse(ex: Exception, resObj: JSONObject) {
    if (_activity == null || _responseHandler == null) return

    _activity.runOnUiThread {
        _responseHandler.invoke(ex, resObj)
    }
}
```

Where both `_activity` and `_responseHandler` are defined as:

```
var _activity: Activity? = null
var _responseHandler: ((Exception, JSONObject) -> Unit)? = null
```

However, the line that calls `runOnUiThread` will only compile if I use `?.` instead of `.`.

I've tried Google searching but I'm afraid my terminology is lacking.  I assumed my null check on the first line of `raiseResponse` was enough to ensure that the `?.` was unecessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that the check and the usage get the value of the property twice. Since `_activity` is a `var`, it can be reassigned (potentially, by another thread) between the check and the usage. It is not null-safe to use the property value, because it can be not the value that was checked, and the compiler requires you to check the value again.

<sup>In other words, the compiler cannot [smart-cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) `_activity` to a non-nullable type.</sup>

You can fix this by storing the value in a local variable (it cannot be changed from outside, so the compiler can prove it's the same value):

```
val activity = _activity
if (activity == null || _responseHandler == null) return

activity.runOnUiThread {
    _responseHandler.invoke(ex, resObj)
}
```

Or, equivalently, use some idiom like `?.let { ... }`:

```
_activity?.let { activity ->
    if (_responseHandler == null) return

    activity.runOnUiThread { // safe, because it is surely the same value
        _responseHandler.invoke(ex, resObj)
    }
} ?: return
```

See also:

- [Best way to handle such scenario where “smart cast is imposible”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246249/best-way-to-handle-such-scenario-where-smart-cast-is-imposible)
- [Kotlin, smart cast is impossible because of complex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612682/kotlin-smart-cast-is-impossible-because-of-complex-expression)
- [In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal with nullable values, referencing or converting them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o)

Comment: Ahh okay excellent.  This makes sense, the scope of `_activity` means that it can be potentially modified after the check but before the call.  I thought it might have been this but was reluctant to make a bunch of local variables before confirming.