# Smart cast to 'TaskAdapter' is impossible, because 'recyclerView.adapter' is a complex expression

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class TodoActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

var id = 0L

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar1)
    val taskList = ArrayList<Task>()
    val task1 = Task(id++, "Task", "Make awesome Tasks", Date())


    taskList.add(task1)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = TaskAdapter(taskList) {
        toast("${it.title}Clicked")

    }


    fab.setOnClickListener {
        taskList.add(Task(id++, "Task${id}", "Description for Task ${id}", Date()))

       recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }


    if (taskList.size > 0)
        tvNotTask.visibility = View.GONE

    else
        tvNotTask.visibility = View.VISIBLE

}


private fun toast(msg: String) = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }
```

this is my code, and when I want to run my App I get this following error

> Smart cast to 'TaskAdapter' is impossible, because 'recyclerView.adapter' is a complex expression

does anybody know what to do I also can add the Layout file if you need to know something from overthere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin, smart cast is impossible because of complex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40612682/kotlin-smart-cast-is-impossible-because-of-complex-expression)

Comment: Can you add TaskAdapter and layout?

Comment: Is your `TaskAdapter` the `android-network-manager` `TaskAdapter` or your own class?